# what is the means of 'variable_name = ModelName'? in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in rails

for example,

```
user = User
```

not,

```
user = User.all
```

is there anyone who knows the meaning of assigning model name to variable?

Comment: The meaning can be found in the following code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby, class names are constant variables that point to the class instance. if you do something like `user = User`, then you can invoke all the User's class methods, such as #new, #name...

Storing a class name in a variable can be useful when you need to dynamically choose between classes.

```
profile = params[:user_type] == "user" ? User : Admin
profile.new(params[:user])
```

Another useful scenario would be to create an alias for long class names nested inside modules:

```
# MyModule::NestedModule::MyLongNamedClass
# is a class with class methods that we're going to use a lot

MyClass = MyModule::NestedModule::MyLongNamedClass

MyClass.classMethod1
MyClass.classMethod3
MyClass.classMethod2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think i understanded completely!

Answer (score 1):

One of the purpose of the code is to use the same interface for many classes 
For example:

```
eating = Time.now.hour == 13 ? Lunch : Nosh
# We drink tee not depending on weather Lunch, Breakfast or Nosh we have
eating.create(tea: 'with sugar')
```

it could be useful if we use STI http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations

Also it is a design pattern named as Abstract Factory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern